# Is it possible to measure string width to properly size a Text composable?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, text-width

I am working on a Jetpack Compose based app which shows a simple list with 3 columns.

[image: Screenshot which shows the 3 columns]

Things are working in principle. What I am struggling with is how to automatically determine the size of the columns.

For example, the width requirement of the date column will differ significantly depending on the user's locale settings and font size.

`24.12.2021 - 20:00` requires a lot less screen space than

`12/14/2021 - 08:00 PM`.

What I was hoping I can do is to work with a sample date, measure it up based on current locale settings and font size and then set the width for all list entries accordingly.

Something similar to this:

```
val d = Date(2021, 12, 30, 23, 59, 59) // Sample date
val t = dateFormat.format(d) + " - " + timeFormat.format(d) // Build the output string
val dateColumnWidth = measureTextWidth(t, fontSize) // This is what I need

…
LazyColumn {
…
Row {
    Text(text = t, Modifier.width(dateColumnWidth.dp), fontSize = fontSize.sp))
    Text(text = value)
    Text(text = comment)
    }
}   
…
```

I have been on this for weeks but a function like my "measureTextWidth" above doesn't seem to exist.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can someone answer my related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72509738/jetpack-compose-finding-text-width-in-dp ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [`SubcomposeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/package-summary#SubcomposeLayout(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function2)) like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MeasureUnconstrainedViewWidth(
    viewToMeasure: @Composable () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable (measuredWidth: Dp) -> Unit,
) {
    SubcomposeLayout { constraints ->
        val measuredWidth = subcompose("viewToMeasure", viewToMeasure)[0]
            .measure(Constraints()).width.toDp()

        val contentPlaceable = subcompose("content") {
            content(measuredWidth)
        }[0].measure(constraints)
        layout(contentPlaceable.width, contentPlaceable.height) {
            contentPlaceable.place(0, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it in your view:

```kotlin
MeasureUnconstrainedViewWidth(
    viewToMeasure = {
        Text("your sample text")
    }
) { measuredWidth ->
    // use measuredWidth to create your view
}
```

Comment: if somebody want to use this function to get height, it will not work properly if your text is multiline, it looks like it have infinit width if not specified. You should restrict max width of viewToMeasure composable like Modifier.widthIn(max = maxWidth.dp)

Comment: @DaniilPozdnyakov in this case you shouldn't override constraints during measurement - I'm doing it with `Constraints()`, you can use `constraints.copy(maxHeight = Constraints.Infinity)` instead

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is a `measureTextWidth` function that measures the width of a given text according to a given [TextStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle), here's the function:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun measureTextWidth(text: String, style: TextStyle): Dp {
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    val widthInPixels = textMeasurer.measure(text, style).size.width
    return with(LocalDensity.current) { widthInPixels.toDp() }
}
```

This function is inspired by [Xam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8781554)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77614718/1071320) in a different thread.

Here is an example of how you would use this function:

```kotlin
val textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 16.sp)
val text = "12/14/2021 - 08:00 PM"
val dateColumnWidth = measureTextWidth(text, textStyle)

Row {
    Text(text = dateTime, Modifier.width(dateColumnWidth), style = textStyle)
    Text(text = value, style = textStyle)
    Text(text = comment, style = textStyle)
}
```