# How can I measure the text width when I use Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose-text

I hope to place a text `val label="100"` near the X-Axis, so I use the Code `it.nativeCanvas.drawText(label, orignX- 40f, canvasHeight, textPaint)` to do it.

I run the Code A, and I get the result Image A.

But I don't know how to measure the width of the text , so I have to kee to test, finally I use approximate value `orignX- 40f`, but it's not a good way.

How can I measure the text width when I use Jetpack Compose?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun setCanvas() {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(2.dp)
    ) {
        val orignX = 100f
        val origY = 100f
        val canvasWidth = size.width-orignX
        val canvasHeight = size.height-origY

        val axisPaint = Paint()
        axisPaint.isAntiAlias = true
        axisPaint.style = PaintingStyle.Stroke
        axisPaint.strokeWidth = 2f
        axisPaint.color = Color.Blue

        val textPaint = TextPaint()
        textPaint.isAntiAlias = true
        textPaint.color = Color.Red.toArgb()
        textPaint.textSize = 15f

        drawIntoCanvas {
            it.drawLine(
                Offset(x = orignX, y = canvasHeight),
                Offset(x = canvasWidth, y = canvasHeight),
                axisPaint
            )

            it.drawLine(
                Offset(x = orignX, y = origY),
                Offset(x = orignX, y = canvasHeight),
                axisPaint
            )

            val label="100"
            it.nativeCanvas.drawText(label, orignX- 40f, canvasHeight, textPaint)
        }

    }

}
```

**Image A**

[image]

Comment: Does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70508246/2016727