# Measuring text width in DP

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, text-width

From [Is it possible to measure string width to properly size a Text composable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70500071/1071320) to find out text width, I have some questions.

I'm a little new to Jetpack Compose so can someone tell how I can call the `measureTextWidth` method mentioned in the above question? I basically need something like:

```
val textWidth = measureTextWidth(Text(text = "Hello World", style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2))
```

Is there any way? Or, what would be the final method definition and call to the `measureTextWidth` method with passing the composable as parameter instead of hardcoding in the `measureTextWidth` method? (I imagine `Text("your sample text")` is hardcoded.)

Comment: I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70508246/3585796) with more general solution, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The `measureTextWidth` method mentioned in the question that you linked to does not exist. The questioner was essentially asking for an implementation of this function.

See my answer in that thread ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77628666/1071320)) for one such implementation of this function.